# A question concerning the Cellular Algebra, which is why $(P\otimes_AC^{\mu\star})\otimes_RC^\mu\cong(\dim P\otimes_AC^{\mu\star})C^\mu$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory, hecke-algebras

Let $A$ be a Cellular Algebra over the integral domain $R$.

Let $C^{\mu\star}$ be a left $A$-module and $C^\mu$ be a right $A$-module.

Let $P=Ae$ be a principal indecomposable $A$-module.

What confused me is why "$(P\otimes_AC^{\mu\star})\otimes_RC^\mu\cong(dimP\otimes_AC^{\mu\star})C^\mu$"?

This question is in line 7 of page 14 of the paper "Iwahori-Hecke Algebras and schur Algebras of the symmetric group"..

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: It might help if you also provide a source for the claim.

Comment: Thank you.  This claim  is in line 7 of page 14 of the paper "Iwahori-Hecke Algebras and schur Algebras of the symmetric group"...I think it may be not intuitively...

Comment: Actually, I missed that the last tensor product is over $R$. This is not related at all to any of the setup but is just a basic thing about tensoring over the base ring (in the absence of a comodule structure).

Comment: Thank you !!      I thought for a while, but it might be difficult for me.. Can you exhibit a little more details such as the tensoring over the base ring..

Comment: Note that the isomorphism is as a right module. And as a right module, the entire module structure of the left side is forgotten (so in general as a right module the tensor product $A\otimes_R B$ just becomes a number of copies of $B$ corresponding to the dimension of $A$ over $R$, since the only things that can be moved across the tensor product are the scalars from $R$).

Comment: I get it! Thank you!......Another question is how to consider  the dimension of $R$-module $A$  if $A$ is not a free $R$-module....It is just  the number of generators of  $A$?..... It may be well known,but I have not find a clear explanation...

Comment: This will depend on context (there are plenty where it is not well-defined). I think the think you are taking dimension of here is projective, which should be enough to have a well-defined dimension.

Comment: Is it just the number of composition factors of A?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46724/discussion-between-tobias-kildetoft-and-yuemingshi).